# Is there any way that I can multiply the first and the last elements in this list?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I'm trying to multiply the first element of this list to the last element and then the second-first element to second-last element and so on. Is there a better way I con do it? tried to do so but I'm reading the same element in 3 times in my inner loop.

```
    long sum = 0;
    long temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; i++) {

        for (int j = list.size() - 1; j >= list.size() / 2; j--) {

            temp = list.get(j) * list.get(i);
            sum += temp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: and you want the sum of all those multiplications? and in case there are odd number of elements, do you want to multiple the middle element with itself?

Comment: Yea, I want to sum of all the multiplications. No, I just wanna leave out because At the moment I'm not dealing with odd elements. .-)

Comment: list [1,2,3,4,5,6] you want 1*6+2*5+3*4?

Comment: @Hamza you need to define the value of j outside the loop, break the inner loop after sum+=temp and increment j afterwards. You can also achieve this using while loops. Check out the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looping over an index from 0 to half of your array length. Then multiply the item at the index with the item at `array length - index - 1`.

```
for(int index = 0; index < (list.size() / 2); index++) {
    sum += (list.get(index) * list.get(list.size() - index - 1));
}
```

Comment: wasn't actually thinking on that way but Know when I saw the code everything makes sense. spent like 4 hrs with two line of codes. GOD. haha. but anyway thanks man

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you are not dealing with odd elements this will work

```
        long sum=0;
        long temp=0;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size()/2;i++)
        {
            temp=list.get(i)*list.get(list.size()-i-1);
            sum+=temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java-8 APIs, you can use `IntStream` go over the `List` indices and use `reduce` to multiply the first and last element and accumulating it as a sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
       int size = list.size() - 1;
       System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, list.size()/2).reduce(0, (acc, ele) ->  { acc += list.get(ele) * list.get(size - ele); return acc;}));
}
```

Comment: just wonder what these acc and ele thing stand for? variables maybe!

Comment: @Hamza yes right, acc or accumulator can be thought of a variable holding the intermediate sum of the product of the first and last elements in your list. The initial 0 is the identity value or in this case the initial value.

Comment: There is no sense in using `+=` in the lambda expression, modifying the parameter is entirely unnecessary. Just use `(acc, ele) -> acc + list.get(ele) * list.get(size - ele)`. If you prefer the block syntax, you can use `(acc, ele) -> { return acc + list.get(ele) * list.get(size - ele); }`, still there is no need to modify the parameter variable. But this is not a correct reduction function anyway, as it is not associative. Use `IntStream.range(0, list.size()/2).map(ele -> list.get(ele) * list.get(size - ele)).sum()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
int i = list.size() / 2;
int j = list.size() - 1;
while (i < list.size() / 2) {

    while ( j >= list.size() / 2;) {

        temp = list.get(j) * list.get(i);
        sum += temp;
        j--;
        break;
    }

    i++;
  }
```